# Dont set pixels into Texture2D if they are transprant

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so Im trying to make a full sprite having it in 2 parts, one sprite with the head and another one with the body.

I set the 2 textures in the inspector and create another one though code that is the one that I want.
What I do is getting the pixels that I want for the body and set them. No problem here, the problem comes when I want to put the head, because its a 128x128 and I dont use all, so it picks transparent pixels of this one and deletes the bodies ones.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MSSGameHandler : MonoBehaviour
{

[SerializeField] private Texture2D baseTexture;
[SerializeField] private Texture2D headTexture;
[SerializeField] private Texture2D bodyTexture;
[SerializeField] private Material guestMaterial;
private Sprite mysprite;

private void Awake()
{
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(512, 512, TextureFormat.RGBA32, true);

    Color[] spriteSheetBasePixels = baseTexture.GetPixels(0, 0, 512, 512);
    texture.SetPixels(0, 0, 512, 512, spriteSheetBasePixels);



    Color[] bodyPixels = bodyTexture.GetPixels(0, 0, 128, 128);
    texture.SetPixels(0, 256, 128, 128, bodyPixels);

    Color[] headPixels = headTexture.GetPixels(0, 0, 128, 128);
    texture.SetPixels(0, 294, 128, 128, headPixels);

    texture.Apply();

    guestMaterial.mainTexture = texture;
    //mysprite = Sprite.Create(texture)

}

}
```

Comment: well in `SetPixels` you overwrite **all** existing pixels yes ...

Comment: yeah, I want to know how to not set if its trasnparent, I dont know if already exists a method or something

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're combining the two textures into one instead of just using two renderers? If you **really** need to create a whole new texture, using a compute shader to combine the two textures might get the result you'd want.

Comment: @Ruzihm yeah, because if I have it in 2 different object the head goes behind the body, and if I change the order the head can go in front of the trees and that stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging these two textures together adds unnecessary loading time at the start of your application for very little per-frame benefit. And, if you decide to move the relative positions of the head and body (e.g., as part of an idle animation), you have to take a performance hit to re-create the new texture showing the new relative positions.

So, instead, put the head and the body into separate objects then use a [Sorting Group component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SortingGroup.html) to keep them sorted together.

Example character:
[image: character made of hierarchy of sprites & gameobjects]

Before sorting group
[image: two characters tangled up]

Apply sorting group to root object (`ChombiBoy`, in this example):
[image: sorting group component on root object]

After sorting group (the character rendered on top has a higher `Order in Layer` in its `Sorting Group`):
[image: two characters displayed correctly]

(images taken from Unity documentation)

> Sorting a Sorting Group
>
> Unity uses the concept of sorting layers to allow you to divide sprites into groups for overlay priority. **Sorting Groups with a Sorting Layer lower in the order are overlaid by those in a higher Sorting Layer.**
>
> Sometimes, two or more objects in the same Sorting Layer can overlap (for example, two player characters in a side scrolling game, as shown in the example below). The Order in Layer property can be used to apply consistent priorities to Sorting Groups in the same layer. **As with Sorting Layer, lower numbers are rendered first, and are obscured by Sorting Groups with higher layer numbers, which are rendered later. See the documentation on Tags and Layers for details on editing Sorting Layers.**
>
> The descendants of the Sorting Group are sorted against other descendants of closest or next Sorting Group (depending on whether sorting is by distance or Order in Layer). **In other words, the Sorting Group creates a local sorting space for its descendants only. This allows each of the Renderers inside the group to be sorted using the Sorting Layer and Order in Layer, but locally to the containing Sorting Group.**

Comment: So with that the sorting order in layer, the original now will act only in the group right? And the group in the world?

Comment: @Alexxjaz Yes, the head and the body `Sprite Renderers` will be rendered one right after the order (in the order determined by their `order in layer` compared to each other) and then the whole group will be sorted in front of or behind trees depending on the `Sorting Group`'s `order in layer`

Comment: Thank you very much, to both for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

well in `SetPixels` you overwrite **all** existing pixels

you should rather loop them "manually" and check the alpha value

```
var finalpixels = new Color[512 * 512];

var spriteSheetBasePixels = baseTexture.GetPixels(0, 0, 512, 512);
for(var i = 0; i < finalpixels.Length; i++)
{
    finalpixels[i] = spriteSheetBasePixels [i];
}

var bodyPixels = bodyTexture.GetPixels(0, 0, 128, 128);
for(var x = 0; x < 128; x++)
{ 
    for(var y = 256; y < 256 + 128; y++)
    {
        finalpixels[x + y * 512] = bodyPixels[x + (y - 256) * 128];
    }
}

var headPixels = headTexture.GetPixels(0, 0, 128, 128);
for(var x = 0; x < 128; x++)
{
    for(var y = 294; y < 294 + 128; y++)
    {
        var pixel = headPixels[x + (y - 256) * 128];

        if(Mathf.Approximately(pixel.a, 0)) continue;

        finalpixels[x + y * 512] = pixel;
    }
}

texture.SetPixels(finalPixels);
```

---

Body image

[image]

Head image

[image]

Result (in a RawImage)

[image]

Sorry for my painting skills :D

Comment: Hey I found my mistake in calculating the index ;) Now it should work ^^

Comment: nominating this answer for best artwork on stackoverflow